# combo box with data template not updating for new rows

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I have a combo box that displays a list with checkboxes, it works fine except that over the course of the day the available options increases, i.e. i add items to the databound list.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb"    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ActiveCommodities}" 
                       IsEditable="True"
                       IsReadOnly="True" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Text="Commodity Filter">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" 
                                      Width="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                       Width="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

I am binding to a property that exposes the values collection of a sorted list

```
   Public ReadOnly Property ActiveCommodities As IList(Of SelectableItem)
        Get
            If Not _activeCommodities Is Nothing Then
                Return _activeCommodities.Values
            End If
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
```

I can set a breakpoint on the get and I see that the count of items in Values is correct, but when it goes up the combobox does not display the new items.

My selected item list looks like this

```
Public Class SelectableItemList
    Inherits SortedList(Of String, SelectableItem)
    Implements INotifyCollectionChanged

    Protected Sub RaiseCollectionChanged(action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction)
        RaiseEvent CollectionChanged(Me, New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action))
    End Sub

    Public Event CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Implements System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged


    Public Overloads Function Add(index As String, text As String) As Boolean
        If Not ContainsKey(index) Then
            Dim si As New SelectableItem(text, Me)
            Add(index, si)
            AddHandler si.PropertyChanged, AddressOf OnSelectionChanged
            RaiseCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

I guess that the problem is because I am binding to the values collection? but I cant figure out how to bind to the sortedcollection and get the data template to work.

Comment: ActiveComodities should be ObservableCollection and not List. You can have a look here for more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Comment: Switched this to a comment, because it doesn't really answer your question completely: Your SelectableItemList implements INotifyCollectionChanged, but you are returning the Values collection, which does not. I would suggest either figuring out how to return your IList directly, or if possible, use the built-in ObservableCollection instead, which supports INotifyCollectionChanged automatically.

Comment: I have switched to the observable collection and am now getting my sorting using the default view and sort descriptions. I guess that when WPF refreshes a combobox from a list it does not look for new items if it is the same instance of the list?

Comment: No, WPF would actually get the new items. The problem was that the class you were returning (a values collection) did not implement INotifyCollectionChanged, so WPF was never even calling your property getter again in the first place.